# Java Math.random повторяет значения. Доска Гальтона

Tags: java, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

Это программа демонстрирует работу доски Гальтона.
Эта доска имеет `N` шт. слот снизу и одна дыра сверху.
Сверху подают шарики которые случайным образом попадают в один из `N` слотов.
Доску используют чтобы исследовать теорию вероятностей.

Смотрите здесь [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Доска_Гальтона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Во время тестирования выявилось, что методы `Math.random(), Random.nextInt(), Random.nextBoolean()` и т.д.
возвращают одинаковые результаты.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Генератор случайных чисел
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // слоты
        int[] slots;

        // количество слотов
        int n;

        // количество шариков
        int balls;

        // показывает на какую сторону катиться шарик false - налево, true - направо
        boolean side;

        // индекс слота в которую должен попасть текущий шарик
        int k;

        // середина массива
        int middle;

        // количество повторения эксперимента
        int times;

        // показывает наибольшое количество шариков в одном слоте
        int max;

        // initialization
        System.out.print("Enter number of repetitions: ");
        times = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of balls: ");
        balls = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of slots: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();
        slots = new int[n];
        middle = n / 2;

        while (times > 0) {
            while (balls > 0) {
                k = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    // "случайный" true или false, от которого зависит значения k
                    side = rand.nextBoolean();
                    k = (side) ? k + 1 : k - 1;
                }

                // так как 2 катание шарика соответствуют одному изменению индекса
                // делим на 2, слагаем алгебраически
                k = middle + k / 2;

                // добавляем шарик в слоте, уменьшаем количество оставшейся шариков
                slots[k]++;
                balls--;
            }

            // находим максимум, рисуем
            max = Max(slots);
            while(max > 0) {
                for(int slot : slots) {
                    if (slot >= max) {
                        System.out.print(" O ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("   ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
                max--;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(slots) + "\n");
            times--;
        }
    }

    public static int Max(int[] array) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[max] < array[i]) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return array[max];
    }
}
```

Несмотря на то, что каждый раз при запуске программы получаются разные случайные значения,
во время выполнения программы при повторении эксперимента в цикле методы возвращают те же
значения с той же последовательностью как при первом попытке.

[image: testing]

Здесь я повторяю эксперимент 2 раз, но 2-ой эксперимент ничем не отличается от 1-ой.
Почему же это так, с чем это связано и как всегда получить уникальные значения?

P.S.
Пробовал

```java
    public static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

и еще в цикле попыток

```java
    while (times > 0) {
        //code...
        rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
   }
   // code...
```

или же

```java
    while (times > 0) {
        //code...
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
   }
   // code...
```

не помогло

Comment: У вас после первой итерации даже во внутренний `while` не заходит (потому что теперь `balls == 0`) и просто выводит старый массив

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon какой я тупой... Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно инициализировать генератор случайных чисел.

```
 Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

По умолчанию инициализпция  идёт одним и тем же числом.

Но основная проблема другая и вы легко увидели бы ее, если бы запустили программу пошагово.

Смотрите:

```
// добавляем шарик в слоте, уменьшаем количество оставшейся шариков
                slots[k]++;
                balls--;
```

Чему будет равно balls после первого прохода по циклу? Понятно, что нулю и при втором проходе вам просто распечатается содержимое slots.

Так как количество шариков в начале каждого прохода должно быть равно введенному с клавиатуры, а слоты должны быть пустые, то инициализацию их нужно проводить перед началом процесса имитация падения шара.

Вот исправленный код.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Генератор случайных чисел
    public static Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // слоты
        int[] slots;

        // количество слотов
        int n;

        // количество шариков
        int balls;

        // показывает на какую сторону катиться шарик false - налево, true - направо
        boolean side;

        // индекс слота в которую должен попасть текущий шарик
        int k;

        // середина массива
        int middle;

        // количество повторения эксперимента
        int times;

        // показывает наибольшое количество шариков в одном слоте
        int max;

        // initialization
        System.out.print("Enter number of repetitions: ");
        times = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter number of balls: ");
        balls = scan.nextInt();
        int balls_current;

        System.out.print("Enter number of slots: ");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        middle = n / 2;


        while (times > 0) {
            balls_current=balls;
            slots = new int[n];
            while (balls_current > 0) {
                k = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    // "случайный" true или false, от которого зависит значения k
                    side = rand.nextBoolean();
                    k = (side) ? k + 1 : k - 1;
                }

                // так как 2 катание шарика соответствуют одному изменению индекса
                // делим на 2, слагаем алгебраически
                k = middle + k / 2;

                // добавляем шарик в слоте, уменьшаем количество оставшейся шариков
                slots[k]++;
                balls_current--;
            }

            // находим максимум, рисуем
            max = Max(slots);
            while(max > 0) {
                for(int slot : slots) {
                    if (slot >= max) {
                        System.out.print(" O ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("   ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
                max--;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(slots) + "\n");
            times--;
        }
    }

    public static int Max(int[] array) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[max] < array[i]) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return array[max];
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему генератор "обнуляется" только во внешнем цикле? Как Java "понимает" что нужно "начинать с начала"?

Comment: Инициализация происходит в момент создания экземпляра класса

Comment: Да я это понимаю, но видите ли значения начинают повторятся когда мы начинаем "все заново", когда уменьшаем счетчик `times` и попадаем в цикл шариков. Почему именно тогда все начинает повторятся? Ведь если бы мы взяли `Random()` без `System.currentTimeMillis()` и в цикле 1_000_000 раз сделали бы `rand.nextInt()` начиная с некоторого `n` числа все значения  с той же последовательностью не повторялись бы точка в точку!

Comment: И кстати `Random(System.currentTimeMillis());` никак не помог

Comment: @ՀայկԱվետիսյան Нашел вторую ошибку и добавил исправленный код.